# GTK Blinks when drawing

Tags: c++, gtk, drawing, gtk3, cairo

I'm really new with GTK, and im trying to learn how to handle it for a project i have in mind.

The thing is, i could manage to make an app for placing "Generators" on a window ... Each time i click on the screen, the app place a gen in the window, and prepare another one ready to be placed ...
The problem is that the program blinks when is drawing all the generators ...
Each gen has to redraw itself all the time, and this is i think the problem... Here is the code ... how can i make it faster? ... Thanks in advance!!

```
    // gcc main.c -o main `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Gen{
public:
  int x;
  int y;
  GdkPixbuf *pix;
  GtkWidget *canvas;
  bool placed;

  Gen(GtkWidget *canvas){
    this->canvas=canvas;
    GError *err = NULL;
    pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("./Img/gen.png", &err);
    pix= gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pix,50,50, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);
    x=10;y=10;
    placed=0;
  }

  void draw(cairo_t *cr){
    gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pix, x, y);
    cairo_paint(cr);
  }

  void updatePosition(int a, int b){
      if(placed==0){
        x=a-25;
        y=b-25;
        }
  }

  void place(){
      placed=1;
  }

};

class Map{
public:
    vector<Gen *> Gens;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *canvas;
    int xPointer,yPointer;

    Map(GtkWidget *_window, GtkWidget *_canvas){
        window=_window;
        canvas=_canvas;
    }

    void draw(){
        cairo_t *cr;
        cr = gdk_cairo_create (gtk_widget_get_window(canvas));
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
        cairo_rectangle(cr, xPointer-35, yPointer-35, 70, 70);
        cairo_paint(cr); 
        for(vector<Gen *>::const_iterator i=Gens.begin();i!=Gens.end();i++){
            (*i)->draw(cr);
        }
        cairo_destroy (cr);   
    }
    void place(){
        Gen *aux=Gens.back(); 
        aux->place();
        //Gens.push_back(new Gen(canvas));
    }
    void moving(int x,int y){
        xPointer=x;yPointer=y;
        if(Gens.size()==0){
            Gens.push_back(new Gen(canvas)); 
        }
        else if (Gens.back()->placed==1){
            Gens.push_back(new Gen(canvas));
        }
        Gen *aux=Gens.back();
        aux->updatePosition(x,y);
        this->draw();
        cout<<"Elementos -> "<<Gens.size()<<"\n";
    }
};





static gboolean
moving(GtkWidget *da, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{

    int x, y;
    GdkModifierType state;
    gdk_window_get_device_position (gdk_event_get_window ((GdkEvent *) event),
                                    gdk_event_get_device ((GdkEvent *) event),
                                    &x, &y, &state);
    /*
    (void)event; (void)data;
    ((Gen *)da)->draw();*/
    Map *g=(Map *)data;
    g->moving(x,y);
}
static gboolean
placing (GtkWidget *da, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{

    Map *g=(Map *)data;
    g->place();

}

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {


    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *canvas;
    gtk_init (&argc , &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window,
        500, 500);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit) , NULL);
    canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    Map *g=new Map(window,canvas);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), canvas);
    gtk_widget_set_events(window, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);

    //g_signal_connect (canvas, "draw", G_CALLBACK (drawing), (gpointer *)g);
    g_signal_connect (window, "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (moving), (gpointer *)g);
    g_signal_connect (window, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (placing), (gpointer *)g);

    //g_signal_connect (canvas, "motion-notify-event", (GCallback) on_window_draw, NULL);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(canvas, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am confused with your code. Do you plan to use C or C++ for your gtk application?

Comment: C++, Sorry i didn't say it :C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several remarks here:
Gen::pix is allocated each time a `Gen` object is created. It's the same pixbuf, but you create one, then another one when using the scaling function (meaning you're leaking memory of the original pixbuf), and this for each `Gen` object. This is really unefficient, so using a static `pix` member, loading then scaling the pixbuf and fixing the memory leak would allow you to do this only once.

Then: you're calling `gdk_cairo_create` in the draw handler, but since GTK 3, you're supposed to get the cairo context as an input parameter in the `draw` signal callback. I see you're calling a custom `draw` method through the motion events, that's not how the GTK+ drawing stack works!

To do it right:

- in the main, connect to the `draw` signal of the GtkDrawingArea
- in your motion callbacks, just change positions of the `Gen` objects, and call `gtk_widget_queue_draw` for the drawing area. This will fire the `draw` signal for you.
- in the callback connected to the `draw` signal, you then redraw your `Gen` objects in the cairo context you're given.
- to improve performance, you can use the cairo clipping functions, or call `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area` or `gtk_widget_queue_draw_region` instead of `gtk_widget_queue_draw`. You'll get then a pre-computed clipping region in the cairo context you'll receive in your `draw` callback. With those hints, you can determine exactly what part of the image needs to be redrawn, and avoid unnecessary work.

Please read [The GTK+ Drawing Model](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-drawing-model.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I really apreciatte your answer! it really helped a lot!